# echo error if $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] exists in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I have a form that will be restricted to one submission per ip.

I'm getting it not to post duplicates but cant seem to get my echo messages displaying correctly.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'MY_USER', 'MY_PWD');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db( 'MY_DB' );
$sql="INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE`(`name`, `last_name`, `state`, `email`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[email]' ,'$_POST[ipaddr]',1,0)";
$result = mysql_query('$_POST[ipaddr]'); 
if (!$result) ==($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) {     

echo '<div id="final">';
echo 'You have already completed the form.';
echo '</div>'; 

} 

else {     

echo '<div id="final">';
echo 'You are a true Patriot. Your details have been added to the wall of patriotism';
echo '</div>';

}  

mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: Which `echo` statements are you referring to? Under what condition? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: OMG, `mysql_query('$_POST[ipaddr]'); ` How this is possible? You are passing a param into `mysql_query`, also your `if` statement were wrong syntax. It may be like this, `if ($result == $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) { `

Comment: on both statements -- The required result would be if the ip exist in mysql the echo should say "you already completed the form" if the ip is not in mysql the echo should say you are a true patriot...."

Comment: I really don't understand the down voting of my question. This is so discouraging. I'm very very new to php and i try my best to first research then ask. But no need to discourage people if the code is incorrect or not written properly it takes no effort just to inform that " Your syntax or structure is incorrect" What you guys don't realize is people like me learn through mistakes as did you when you started coding no need to discourage or be nasty because you know way more than i do.

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake in your query

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE`(`name`, `last_name`, `state`, `email`, `ipaddr`) VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[email]' ,'$_POST[ipaddr]',1,0)";
```

The number of values mismatched. You have to pass only 5 values instead of 7 and make use of `'"`

`('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['last_name']."','".$_POST['state']."','".$_POST['email']."' ,'".$_POST['ipaddr']."')";`

And, I think these statements are really invalid.

```
$result = mysql_query('$_POST[ipaddr]'); 
if (!$result) ==($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution on this but i'm still not getting my echo messages correct. if the ip exist in mysql the echo should say "you already completed the form" if the ip is not in mysql the echo should say you are a true patriot...."

Comment: you are not using `mysql_query` in a proper manner. Please refer some tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
Wrong code :
$sql="INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE`(`name`, `last_name`, `state`, `email`, `ipaddr`)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[email]' ,'$_POST[ipaddr]',1,0)";
$result = mysql_query('$_POST[ipaddr]'); 
if (!$result) ==($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) 

Here your insert sql statement (`name`, `last_name`, `state`, `email`, `ipaddr`) five fields and ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[email]' ,'$_POST[ipaddr]',1,0) seven values.
Put place of mysql_query('$_POST[ipaddr]') to mysql_query($sql).
if (!$result) ==($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) not valid statement.
```